# why does my aspect code not run when exception is thrown?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

In my `spring` project I've added two dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and then I've created a class:

```
package com.my.company.package.handling;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.my.company.package.*(..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void logAfterThrowing(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("exception "+ex.getLocalizedMessage())
    }
}
```

Now in some other class (stored in package: `com.my.company.package.someOtherPackage`) I'm throwing exception:

```
throw new IOException("here comes error");
```

but then I don't see the printout from my aspect method in the console. What am I missing here?

Comment: isn't there missing a `.*`  for the method name? I don't use AspectJ but documentation states: *"execution of any method defined in the service package: `execution(* com.xyz.service.*.*(..))`"* (assuming that your `someOtherPackage` is a **class**), or: *" execution of any method defined in the service package or a sub-package: `execution(* com.xyz.service..*.*(..))`"*

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger just realised the same thing, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything else is correct you need a @Component annotation also, you also need another * in the execution string for any class.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.my.company.package.*.*(..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void logAfterThrowing(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("exception "+ex.getLocalizedMessage())
    }
}
```

Here's a working [example](https://github.com/gregclinker/aspect-example/tree/master/src/main/java/hello)

Comment: Thanks, however when I used it - I'm not seeing the message from `logAfterThrowing`. I tried to invoke it in my code by throwing e.g. `throw new ParseException("msg", 0)` or `throw new NullPointerException("msg");` but message from Aspect does not show up

Comment: @randomuser1 it works for me in the test, something else wrong?